# Minimum Covariance Determinant sci kit learn implementation

Tags: scikit-learn

Sci kit learn has an implementation of the Minimum Covariance Determinant Estimator ( **model = sklearn.covariance.MinCovDet()** ).

As you fit the data ( **model.fit(X)** ) two different covariances are estimated, which are stored as attributes:

1. The first is **model.raw_covariance_** described in the documentation as "The raw robust estimated covariance before correction and re-weighting ".
2. The second is **model.covariance_** described as "Estimated robust covariance matrix".

There are two methods that seem to compute two more different covariances:

1. **model.correct_covariance(X)** is said to "Apply a correction to raw Minimum Covariance Determinant estimates."
2. **model.reweight_covariance(x)** is said to "Re-weight observations using Rousseeuw’s method (equivalent to deleting outlying observations from the data set before computing location and covariance estimates)."

Can anyone explain the difference between all these?

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting question, but probably a candidate for `stats`.

Comment: You suggest I move the question to stackexchange? Is there a way of linking it directly from here or do I have to write it again in that exchange?

Comment: High reputation users can vote for migration. You don't have to do anything. If enough people agree that it should be moved, the question automatically moves to a partner site.